# Are there any methods to modifying properties of all tables at a time for google docs?

Tags: google-docs

I have written a article in my google docs.

I have included small tables, big tables and huge tables in different places in the files.

Now I need to modify some properties of all tables at a time.

But that seems not possible?

Are there any methods to modifying properties of all tables at a time for google docs?

**PS. more details to illustrate my issue:**

**1. Here is a doc file with one table.**
[image]

**2. Right click on the table and choose Table properties**
 [image]

**3. Now here comes more tables in a doc file**
[image]

**How can I deal with all the tables together? (All modifications are the same)**

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `modifying properties of all tables at a time for google docs`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hi, Tanaike . I've added details

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. Although I couldn't understand about the detail of modifications you expect from your additional information, for example, how about using a script? When the script is used, the same modification can be reflected to the tables. But I'm not sure about the detail of the modifications you expect. So I'm not sure whether this proposal is suitable for your actual situation. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method 1

When creating the tables, you can simply set all the properties on the first one and then for the next ones you can copy and paste the first one since the format will be kept.

### Method 2

If you want to modify more tables at the same time, you can make use of Apps Script.

Apps Script is a powerful development platform which can be used to build web apps and automate tasks. What makes it special is the fact that it is easy to use and to create applications that integrate with G Suite.

Therefore, your task can be achieved by using this script.

#### Snippet

```
function setTableProperties() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById("DOCUMENT_ID");
  var tables = doc.getBody().getTables();

  tables.forEach((table) => {
    //Any instruction run with the variable table will be executed for all tables.
  });
}
```

#### Explanation

The above script gathers all the tables from the wanted document and then using a `for` loop accesses each table from the document.

In order to set the properties of the tables as wanted, you just have to use the appropriate method/s.

The `getAttributes` method can be used as well in order to see exactly which properties does a table posses.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Document Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document);
- [Apps Script Enum Attribute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document#properties);
- [Apps Script Table Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table);
- [Apps Script DocumentApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app).